# .filter with a map in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, rendering

I am using data that is returned via a graphql query. Each of the user relations object looks like this:

```
"userRelations": [
    {
      "relatedUser": {
        "id": 4,
        "firstName": "Jack",
        "lastName": "Miller"
      },
      "type": "FRIEND"
    },
    {
      "relatedUser": {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Rhena",
        "lastName": "Tahoma"
      },
      "type": "CONTACT"
    }
  ]
```

Currently, my code renders all `relatedUsers` regardless of what their `type`is. However, I only want to render those which have `"type": "contact"`. I am trying to use the `. filter`function but I am unable to do so.

```
type UserProps = {
  data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult;
};

type RelatedUser = {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    id: string,
    phoneNumber: string,
  };

  type RelationType = {
    type: string,
  };

export const ContactList: React.FunctionComponent<UserProps> = ({ data }) => {
  if (!data) return null;

  return (
    <View style={styles.users}>
    {data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.map(
      (item: { relatedUser: RelatedUser, type: RelationType}) => {
        // if (item.type: "CONTACT"){
        return (
          <View style={styles.item} key={item.relatedUser.id}>
           ...
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      },
    )}
  </View>
  );
};
```

I tried using this: `data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.filter(({ type }) => type === 'CONTACT').map(/*code*/)`

but it gives me an error that:

```
Binding element 'type' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)
```

If I add `: RelationType` infront of type, I get `'RelationType' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133) Binding element 'RelationType' implicitly has an 'any' type`

What else can I do to filter out and map/render only CONTACT types.

Comment: what is `UsersLazyQueryHookResult`?  Where is `View` imported from?

Comment: ```UsersLazyQueryHookResult```is the type of data returned via graphql. It's generated by codegen. The sample data I copied above is from the grapqhl playground. View is from native base. @J'e

Comment: **I think** the binding type error you're getting is because typescript doesn't want you to use **any** which is likely from your ts config.  Based on the three individual types you have listed above, `data.users.nodes[0].userRelations` has a type of any. Try adding a 4th type `type Foo = { relatedUser: RelatedUser; type: RelationType };`. then `(data.users.nodes[0].userRelations as Foo).filter...`

Comment: ```{(data.users.nodes[0].userRelations as UserRelation).filter().map()````gives me ```Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'UserRelation'.```. UserRelation is Foo. @J'e

Comment: sorry, it needs to be an array `(data.users.nodes[0].userRelations as UserRelation[])`

Comment: I tried adding it before my map but it gives me errors like ```Argument of type '(item: {    relatedUser: RelatedUser;    type: RelationType;    id: number;}) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: UserRelation, index: number, array: UserRelation[]) => Element'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'UserRelation' is not assignable to type '{ relatedUser: RelatedUser; type: RelationType; id: number; }'.```@J'e

Comment: "I tried adding it before my map..." do you still have it inside the return statement?

Comment: Yes, I need to render items so I'm using it inside the return @J'e